# How to call SharePoint Rest api in MS Flow using HTTP action

Tags: api

Is it possible to call SharePoint Rest API in MS Flow Action (HTTP Action)?

I tried SharePoint Rest call with Bearer access token. I am getting this Error Message:

> HTTP Error 400. The request host name is invalid